# How to chop off file:// from NSURL

Tags: cocoa, path, nsurl

I have an NSURL.
It is file://localhost/Users/Me/File.xml

I want an NSString that is /Users/Me/File.xml

Is there some nice function I can use to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

NSURL [path](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path) method sounds like it does what you want.

Comment: …generally preceded by `-isFileURL`.

Comment: `.path`! How could I miss that? :D